# Are there any alternatives to ESAPI

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, esapi

We are splitting our logging functionality as a separate logging library which will be used as a logging jar for all web application. Currently we are using ESAPI 2.1 to prevent log forging, we have also upgraded our logging framework to log4j 2 to support async logging.

From this post https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170523/is-owasp-esapi-still-the-recommended-way-to-secure-jsp-pages , I came to know that ESAPI seems to be outdated and not used anymore, is there any better alternative to create a secure logging library?

Answer (score 2):

Dead you say?  [Oh Really?](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/master/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.2.0.0-release-notes.txt)

At any rate, if you just want our logging capabilities just `git clone https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy` and copy the code you like while respecting our FreeBSD license.

Also, if its log injection that you're worried about, also come to an agreement on a log format message that always encloses user input in symbols you control.  Makes it easier to detect mischief.

Comment: So can you give me some documentation sites on how to use esapi for log4j 2

Comment: I'm not sure we support log4j 2.x _directly_. I think you have to do it via using logback, which ESAPI 2.2.0.0 now supports (and maybe then use the log4j bridge for logback). If you pull down the source from GitHub and grep the JUnit tests under src/test you should find some examples of where logback is being used in a test.

Comment: We support slf4j now?

Comment: Since we are building a logger component as a jar from scratch we would like the libraries used in it to be supported for long enough. The plan is to use SLF4j with Log4j2 and secure the logging with ESAPI . The logs will be primarily viewed either in a text editor such as notepad++ or using putty or using a browser.The developers who are building spring based web applications will import this jar as a dependency as their logging framework.